# Cron Task to Run query based on users midnight

Tags: php, time

I have a php script being run every hour to connect to a database to do some "Nightly Resets" that's supposed to happen at the users Midnight.

I have what timezone the user is in, but, can't figure out how to calculate the timezone where it's currently midnight.

So I can run a query something like ...WHERE timezone='-6'   ect...

Comment: How is the user's timezone stored?

Comment: how do you record what timezone a user is in?

Comment: It is unclear what data you have and what data want. Please clarify your question to include example data of what is stored in the database and an example of what value your variables have.

Comment: could probably do it through a combination of using `DateTime` and `DateTimeZone::getOffset()`

Comment: Their timezone is coming from Facebook. It's a UTC Offset. I'm in -6(Central) -5 with DST